# How to connect to Android to Raspberry Pi through Bluetooth

Tags: raspbian, bluetooth

I have been trying to connect my Raspberry Pi B+ with my phone through Bluetooth, my Android phone is also paired with the Pi but couldn't connect.
I also tried to connect from terminal using `bluetoothctl` and starting agent but the same - I couldn't connect.

The error which pops up saying:

> couldn't find any suitable service on this device

I need to connect my phone to use as Bluetooth mic and also to control my GPIO pins.